# Compass / Blueprint has a CSS rule "body.bp table" and "body.bp td" and mess up all the tables, what's a workaround?

Tags: css, rubygems, blueprint-css, compass-sass

I have CSS definitions such as

```
.one-table
  width: 500px

.one-table td
  padding: 0
```

but since Compass / Blueprint 0.8.17 has

```
body.bp table { width: 100% }
body.bp td { padding: 4px }
```

so my tables are messed up.  And adding `table.one-table` doesn't help either.  I think it is losing to the specificity...  which I am quite surprised because the class is directly onto the table, while the other one has the class applied onto `body`.  Why is that overridden and what is a good workaround for it?

I can't use `id` because it is a template and I need to make it generic enough.  I also feel reluctant to use `!important` because what if later the IE css def needs to use important also.  I can't upgrade to the newest compass because doing so might mean fixing things for the whole website too.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a how to calculate [CSS specificity](http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/). id selector has a specificity of 100, class selector 10, and element selector 1. To calculate the CSS specificity, just sum the values.

`body.bp table`'s specificity is 12 (1 + 10 + 1) and `table.one-table` is 11 (1 + 10), so `body.bp table` wins.

To fix this while keeping the `one-table` class, you can try using these selectors:

```
# Specifity is 20 (vs 12).
.bp .one-table
  width: 500px

# Specifity is 21 (vs 12).
.bp .one-table td
  padding: 0
```

Or you can just use the same selectors and override the blueprint rules. These rules will apply to all tables though.

```
# This must come after the blueprint rules.
body.bp table
  width: 500px

body.bp td
  padding: 0
```

It seems that the blueprint mixin is scoped to the class `bp`. This may cause you to have to put `.bp` in front of many of your CSS rules. If the blueprint scoping is not necessary, you should just use the top-level mixin for blueprint:

```
+blueprint
```

Comment: if using `.bp .one-table  width: 500px` then i will have to also style it as `table.bp.one-table` huh?  This is so subtle... that if somebody changes blueprint to `body.bp.local`, then the other rule will fail again?  Specificity applies even when that class if not directly for that element huh... that's a little weird.

Comment: No, you can still use `table.one-table` for your CSS rule. The `.bp` is meant to select `body.bp`.